# .click() fails after dom change

Tags: jquery, dom, click

I searched on web but I didn't find any answer since this "problem" is not the usual one about the difference between .on() and .click().
With jquery 2.1.3 the click function is a shortand for `on.("click", handler)` so it should fire a function (or wathever) after the dom is changed.
But this works only if I use .on().
Why? (Example below)

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('div').html("<p id="button2">Hello</p>");
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    alert(0); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
});

$(body).on("click", "#button2", function() {
    alert(0); //THIS WORKS!
});
```

Comment: Even though it is a shorthand `on(event, handler)`, you are still attaching it to `$('#button2')` which doesn't exist yet; that's why there is `on(event, selector, handler)`

Comment: You should use `on` for dynamically created elements.

Comment: @hamed you can also use `click` but then you wont have selector matching  : http://jsbin.com/cifomehula/2/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But this works only if I use .on().

First of all , you should realize that :

If

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
    alert(0); 
});
```

comes *after*

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('div').html("<p id="button2">Hello</p>");
});
```

like :

```
   $('#button1').click(function() {
        $('div').html("<p id="button2">Hello</p>");
        $('#button2').click(function() {
          alert(0); 
      });
    });
```

Then it WILL work.

the thing which you did in the last code is attaching the handler to the body element which is working because of event propagation.

your code is working beacuse `on` allows you to do selector matching  + attaching single handler to the body element.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('div').html("<p id='button2'>Hello</p>");
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
    alert(0); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
});

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function() {
    alert(0); //THIS WORKS!
});
```

This is correct code

https://jsfiddle.net/hhe3npux/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is if you added data dynamically, then you must use `.on` function. With this code, you can use event delegation concept by using the code that you mention at last. Since the DOM are not registered yet, the .click handler cant capture the new DOM element.