# JQuery - Click listener not firing when trigger classes are swapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery on click listener that looks for class 'install-plugin'.

When clicked, it changes the class (via jQuery) to 'delete-plugin'.

And vice versa, so there is a listener for 'delete-plugin' that, when clicked, changes the class to 'install-plugin'.

The problem I have is that this only works once, and although I can see the classes have updated on the page correctly, jQuery doesn't seem to see that and still fires the original listener.

(The ajax is necessary for the intended, extended functionality). Is it possible to have jQuery always be up to date with what's on the page without hard refreshing it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.install-plugin').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var postData = {
            action : 'install_plugin',
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#'+id).text('Delete');
                $('#'+id).removeClass('install-plugin');
                $('#'+id).addClass('delete-plugin');
            }
        });
    })

    $('.delete-plugin').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var postData = {
            action : 'delete_plugin',
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: postData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#'+id).text('Install');
                $('#'+id).removeClass('delete-plugin');
                $('#'+id).addClass('install-plugin');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'on' syntax, e.g. $(selector).on('click', function(event){....}) for dynamically changed elements.

[.click() fails after dom change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000326/click-fails-after-dom-change)

Comment: Also can assign (delegate)  a listener on a parent element that will always be present in the DOM. This will listen for example, for a click event on a DOM element that is added into the page later. See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-plugin', function() {
   // your delete logic here
});

$(document).on('click', '.install-plugin', function() {
   // your install logic here
});
```

Your issue is that you bind only once your clickHandlers on `$('.install-plugin')` respectively `$('.delete-plugin')`. My suggestation prevent this behavior.

BTW:
You can simplify your code in your ajax successHandler.

```
`$('#'+id).text('Delete')
          .removeClass('install-plugin')
          .addClass('delete-plugin');`
```

You can put also all in on function like:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.install-plugin, .delete-plugin', function() {
       var action = ($(this).hasClass('install-plugin')) ? 'install_plugin' : 'delete_plugin';

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var postData = {
            action : action,
        }

       ....
    });
```