# PHP while loop submit button doesn't work in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP while loop which gets test_id for quizzes from mysql db and creates button for each unique test_id. So all quizzes show up on a page as follows:

cant upload an image so it's on imgur.com
[list of quizzes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjyGd.png)

My method for displaying the quizzes and to capture button click is
    as follows:
    1. txtHint displays the quiz list
    2. take-quiz is button id 
    3. test_id is sent using a hidden input type which has unique test_id which changes with each while loop.

```
$.ajax({

                    type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
                    url: url,
                    data: loginString,
                    success: function(data1){
                            localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
                     $("#txtHint").html(data1);

                    $("#take-quiz").click(function(){


                            // update profile.php,
                            var test_id= $.trim($("#test_id").val());


                            localStorage.setItem("test_id", test_id);
                            window.location.href = "take-quiz.html";


               });

                }
                });
```

Here is some php code within while loop which shows the button and hidden test_id

```
$createTable .= '<input type="hidden" value="';
    $createTable .= $row['id'];
    $createTable .= '"  id="test_id" />';
    $createTable .= '<input type="submit" value="Take Quiz " name="take-quiz" id="take-quiz" class="btn btn-primary"/>';
```

This list is displayed using AJAX html element. 
when I try to click the buttons only the first result button works, others don't do anything. If i try to bind the click event to the document each button works but I get the same test_id for each button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#take-quiz', function(e) {
    alert(...);
});
```

I looked at another question on SO which is a duplicate :[Cant click on button with is loaded with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427169/cant-click-on-button-with-is-loaded-with-ajax?answertab=active#tab-top) but I cannot get it to resolve my errors.

Can someone please shed some light on what I am doing wrong ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs with the html id test_id?

Comment: yes, its in a while loop so every time it loops, there are multiple values with test_id

Comment: Also, be sure you don't depend on checking the localStorage `localStorage.loginstatus = "true";` to see if the usr is logged in or not. This is easily spoofed. Instead save it in a session variable and check that session variable when the page loads.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can only have one on the page at a time

Comment: @VVV many thanks for loginstatus tip. @Kyle; many thanks for the unique ID tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace your duplicate IDS with a class. IDS must be unique per page and not duplicated. Second, you will want to change your click handler to take into consideration the class as well as remove it from the ajax.

```
$createTable .= '<input type="hidden" value="';
    $createTable .= $row['id'];
    $createTable .= '"  class="test_id" />';
    $createTable .= '<input type="submit" value="Take Quiz " name="take-quiz" class="btn btn-primary take-quiz"/>';



  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",crossDomain: true, cache: false,
    url: url,
    data: loginString,
    success: function(data1){
        localStorage.loginstatus = "true";
        $("#txtHint").html(data1);
    }
});

$(document).on("click",".take-quiz",function(){
    var test_id= $.trim($(this).prev().val());
    localStorage.setItem("test_id", test_id);
    window.location.href = "take-quiz.html";
});
```

Comment: excellent direction @imvain2 , i spent many hours on this error until finally your answer on class helped a lot. I had to change the name="take-quiz"  to class="take-quiz" so had 2 class attributes in my submit button which also changed the design of the button, can you please tell me why this works : var test_id= $.trim($(this).prev().val()); and not this : var test_id= $.trim($(".test_id").val());

Comment: @Abey, the reason I didn't refer to the class was when you have multiple objects with the same class you need a way to differentiate a way to refer to them. I chose to use the `prev` because it was the only way to refer to the test_id that is associated with that button with your current layout. Now if you wrapped each hidden and button together in their own div, then you could use `$(this).parent("div").find(".test_id").val()`.

Comment: many thanks for the reply. helped a lot in understanding this :) so if i need to get data from multiple class elements, i can wrap them in a div and get it like above. thanks..

Comment: Just a tip for others out there: I had to change the name="take-quiz" attribute to class="take-quiz btn btn-primary" to keep the button design intact.