# Function not runs by button click after id change (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Button and change it id via `javascript`

**Here is code:**

```
 //unlock inputs and change button
function updateAppointment() {
    $('#doctor').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#findingareavalue').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#noticevalue').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#findingcontent').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#procedurecontent').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#editapp').text('Save');
    $('#editapp').attr('id', 'saveappointment');
}
```

After that I try to run function by `saveappointment` button.

**Here is code:**

```
$('#saveappointment').click(function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
 function saveUpdatedAppointment() {
    var model = {
        doctorname: $('#doctor').val(),
        findingareavalue: $('#findingareavalue').val(),
        noticevalue: $('#noticevalue').val(),
        findingcontent: $('#findingcontent').val(),
        procedurecontent: $('#procedurecontent').val(),
        appId: parseInt($('#appointmentId').text())

    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateApp", "PatientDatabase")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#saveappointment').text('Edit');
            $('#saveappointment').attr('id', 'editapp');
        }
    });
}
```

But code is'nt running. I don't have errors in dev console.
ID of button is changing.

```js
 $('#editapp').click(function () {
     updateAppointment();
});
 function updateAppointment() {
    $('#editapp').text('Save');
    $('#editapp').attr('id', 'saveappointment');
}

$('#saveappointment').click(function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
 function saveUpdatedAppointment() {
 $('#saveappointment').text('Edit');
 $('#saveappointment').attr('id', 'editapp');
 $( "#editapp").off("click"); // unbind the click from the button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="editapp">
Edit
</button>
```

In what may be problem?

Comment: What is `alert();` for?

Comment: Just check if button click is working.@Eddie

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000417/9104335

Comment: Is it working? Are you able to alert?

Comment: Nope. If yes,I would not write this question@Eddie

Comment: It woks but I get 2 alerts , when click button when it had 'editapp' id and when it has `saveppointment` id @posoppis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind an event to an element, `jQuery` bind that event to that element, no matter what happens to the id of the element, the event will remian, you need to unbind it using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```js
 function updateAppointment() {
    $('#doctor').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#findingareavalue').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#noticevalue').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#findingcontent').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#procedurecontent').prop('readonly', false);
    $('#editapp').text('Save');
    $('#editapp').attr('id', 'saveappointment');
}

$('#saveappointment').click(function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
 function saveUpdatedAppointment() {
    var model = {
        doctorname: $('#doctor').val(),
        findingareavalue: $('#findingareavalue').val(),
        noticevalue: $('#noticevalue').val(),
        findingcontent: $('#findingcontent').val(),
        procedurecontent: $('#procedurecontent').val(),
        appId: parseInt($('#appointmentId').text())

    }
    // remove ajax code
 $('#saveappointment').text('Edit');
 $('#saveappointment').attr('id', 'editapp');
 $( "#editapp").off("click"); // unbind the click from the button
 $( "#editapp" ).bind( "click", function(){
     alert("new bind");
 } );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="saveappointment"> save app</button>
```

Comment: See my updated snippet in post. It get alert when I click button when it is edit.

Comment: you can remove that code, I have added to show you, that you can bind another event.

Comment: Okay, but now I have problem with alerts

Comment: Oh, sorry ,I'm confused. All ok now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you register click event for `saveappointment`, this element still not exit at this time. So you need to register event for this element after you change to new id.

```js
$('#editapp').click(function() {
        updateAppointment();
    });
function saveAppointment() {
alert();
}

function updateAppointment() {
      $('#editapp').text('Save');
    $('#editapp').attr('id', 'saveappointment');
        $('#saveappointment').unbind('click').click(saveAppointment);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="editapp">
Edit
</button>
```

Comment: I added fiddle to post

Comment: But I need my click of `saveappointment` outside of `updateAppointment`  function. Why it in it?

Comment: See my snippet in post.

Comment: @e.d I can help you solve this error, but design like this not good, have many boilerplate code. do you wanna me support simpler design.

Comment: Yes. I want you to support simpler design

Comment: @e.d added as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

please try to change you handler to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveappointment', function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
```

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000422/9104335)

Comment: It woks but I get 2 alerts , when click button when it had 'editapp' id and when it has saveppointment id

Comment: I added fiddle.

Comment: it seems that jquery matches different events... please see the other answers for a better solution

Comment: @e.d yes, you could even chain it together with the existing line of code that updates the ID: `$('#editapp').off('click').attr('id', 'saveappointment');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#editapp').click(function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
 function updateAppointment() {
    $('#editapp').text('Save');
    $('#editapp').attr('id', 'saveappointment');
}

$('#saveappointment').click(function () {
    alert();
    saveUpdatedAppointment();
});
 function saveUpdatedAppointment() {
 $('#saveappointment').text('Edit');
 $('#saveappointment').attr('id', 'editapp');
 $( "#editapp").off("click"); // unbind the click from the button
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="editapp">
Edit
</button>
```

```js
const action_text_save = "save";
const action_text_edit = "edit";
$('#actionApp').click(function () {
     if($(this).hasClass(action_text_edit)) {
       updateAppointment();
     } else {
       saveAppointment();
     }
     switchAction();
});

function switchAction() {
var actionBtn = $('#actionApp');
  if (actionBtn.hasClass(action_text_edit)) {
    actionBtn.removeClass(action_text_edit);
    actionBtn.text(action_text_save);
    actionBtn.addClass(action_text_save);
  } else {
    actionBtn.removeClass(action_text_save);
    actionBtn.text(action_text_edit);
    actionBtn.addClass(action_text_edit);
  }
}


function saveAppointment() {
  alert("appointment is saved");
}

function updateAppointment() {
 alert("appointment is updated");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id ="actionApp" class="edit">
Edit
</button>
```